# remove lightning buttons from page layout

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-quickaction

I have a custom object which is related to contact. i am getting the following detail page for the custom object

[image]

i am not being able to understand at all where the new Opportunity and new Contact buttons are coming from. They are not lightning quick actions or global actions. can anyone tell me from where can i remove it.

Comment: Did you check the Mobile & Lightning Action section on Page layout?

Comment: yes i did. it is not in that section either.

Comment: please upload a print screen of your current page layout editor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check your custom object layout;

[image: Salesforce Mobile and Lightning Experience Actions]

If the red highlighted area as above screenshot, then click there, it will be as below )or it's already as below.

[image]

Then you can drag&drop the buttons away from the area.